# Magento 1.9 custom order attribute not saved (EAV_entity_text)

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

In my customer Magento module I've added a custom attribute (hearedfrom) to an order, the attribute is set in the order object (get after set returns the values) but it doens't seem to get saved in the DB.

mymodule/etc/config.xml

```html
 <resources>
   <hearedfrom_setup>
     <setup>
        <module>Brainworx_Hearedfrom</module>
     <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
     </setup>
     <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
     </connection>
  </hearedfrom_setup>
</resources>
```

MySqlInstall

```js
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

//get the entity type for orders
$sql = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM ".$this->getTable('eav_entity_type')." WHERE entity_type_code='order'";
Mage::Log("Hearedfrom: " .$sql);
$row = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchRow($sql);
   
$attribute  = array(
 'type'   => 'text',
 'label'   => 'Hearedfrom',
 'visible'  => true,
 'required'  => false,
 'user_defined' => true,
 'searchable' => true,
 'filterable' => true,
 'comparable' => false,
);
//add attribute for the sale/order
$installer->addAttribute($row['entity_type_id'], 'hearedfrom', $attribute);

$installer->endSetup();
```

The observer where I save a value in the new attribute.

```js
public function hookToOrderSaveEvent()
 {
  /**
  * NOTE:
  * Order has already been saved, now we simply add some stuff to it,
  * that will be saved to database. We add the stuff to Order object property
  * called "hearedfrom"
  */
  $order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
  $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
  $order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
  
  //Fetch the data from select box and throw it here
  $_hearedfrom_data = null;
  $_hearedfrom_data = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getBrainworxHearedfrom();
  //$this->_getRequest()->getPost(‘myCustomerOrderComment’, false);
  Mage::Log("Order brought by: ".$_hearedfrom_data);
  
  //Save fhc id to order obcject
  $order->setData(self::ORDER_ATTRIBUTE_FHC_ID, $_hearedfrom_data);
  Mage::Log("test: ".$order->getHearedfrom());
  $order->save();
 }
```

In my log I can see the value before and after setting it in my $order.
The Data has an entry for the value.
In the DB I can see an enty in EAV_ATTRIBUTE linked to EAV_ENTITY_TYPE and EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE.
But I would expect the saved value to be in EAV_ENTITY_TEXT which doesn't contain any records.

After reloading the placed order it doesn't contain the customer attribute.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Can you see your attribute in the sales_flat_order table?

If not I believe your problem is using a Catalog setup instead of a Sales one. Try using **Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup** setup class instead. Add the attribute like this instead:

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'), 'hearedfrom', array(
'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
'nullable' => true,
'default' => 0
));
```

Also clean magento caches. I believe some SQL queries are still cached even if they are all disabled. When the order is saved to the database, a DESCRIBE SQL query will determine which properties are saved in the database. 
I ran into a problem recently where the describe query didn't include my new column so the value was not saved.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by hooking my handler to the order_save_after_event instead order_save_event